# $.get route is not being called on server-side, and no data is being returned, server not console logging

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, get

I don't know what happened, but for some reason $.get just doesn't work anymore. I'm trying to make it as basic as possible and it still doesn't work. I have this code:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    console.log("I'm in the on click event");


    $.get("/test", function(data) {
        console.log("IM HERE BUT WHY??");
        console.log(data);
            });
})
```

When I click the button, here's the server-side route:

```
  router.get("/test", function(req, res) {
    console.log("HELLO?");
    console.log(req);
    res.json(req.body);
  })
```

... I don't get the "HELLO?" console log, but I get the "I'm on the click event!", so it looks like the on click event is working.

Also, for some reason, other routes work. But any new ones that I make just don't work. For example, this code works from the front-end:

```
  function getStock() {

    $.get("/api/new/" + stock.name, function(data) {


      stock = {
          ticker: data.ticker,
          price: data.price
      }
        allStocks.push(stock);
        console.log(allStocks);
        console.log(allStocks[0])
        console.log(allStocks[1])
      createNewRow(stock);
    });
  }
```

When I look at the network tab in the chrome Developer tools window, I see this:
[What is happening??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z57xE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I think I just figured out.

[If you check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLyPb.png)

I think it's because I am using passport. So I have two files in my Server folder. One is "account.js", another is "apiRoutes", I use the account.js for my "/login", "/register" routes for when i'm using authentication.

I'm not exactly sure why but it works in my apiRoutes file, not my "account.js" file. Would anyone be able to tell me why? Sorry, i'm very new to programming!